# How to write Clojure data as EDN to an Node.js output-stream?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript

I have a very large clojure map `data` and an `output-stream` created from a file.

```clj
(let [data {:very "large"}
      output-stream (-> ^js file .createWriteStream))]
```

My current solution is to create an EDN string with `pr-str`, create a `Readable` and and pipe it to the output-stream.

```clj
(ns user
  (:require ["stream" :as stream]))

(let [s (pr-str data)
      Readable (-> stream .-Readable)
      readable (-> Readable (.from s)]
  (-> readable (.pipe output-stream (clj->js {:end false})))
  (-> readable (.on "end" (fn []
                            (resolve output-stream)))))
```

Is there a better solution? Perhaps without creating the string and the Readable?